# JavaScript Issues when Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add an accordion menu to my company's website and for some reason the HTML and CSS load fine, but the JS does not seem to be loading on the page. I am using a template that works on Code Pen, so I am thinking that most likely it is an issue with where/how I am putting the JS in. Any advice? I have put the following code into the  section of the webpage [https://www.nlfxpro.com/meet-our-team/](https://www.nlfxpro.com/meet-our-team#):

```
<script>
/*!
 * classie - class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 */


( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );

//fake jQuery
var $ = function(selector){
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}
var accordion = $('.acc');





//add event listener to all anchor tags with accordion title class
accordion.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A") {
    var classes = e.target.className.split(" ");
    if(classes) {
      for(var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {
        if(classes[x] == "acc_title") {
          var title = e.target;

          //next element sibling needs to be tested in IE8+ for any crashing problems
          var content = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;

          //use classie to then toggle the active class which will then open and close the accordion

          classie.toggle(title, 'acc_title_active');
          //this is just here to allow a custom animation to treat the content
          if(classie.has(content, 'acc_panel_col')) {
            if(classie.has(content, 'anim_out')){
              classie.remove(content, 'anim_out');
            }
            classie.add(content, 'anim_in');

          }else{
             classie.remove(content, 'anim_in');
             classie.add(content, 'anim_out');
          }
          //remove or add the collapsed state
          classie.toggle(content, 'acc_panel_col');




        }
      }
    }

  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You'll need to clarify on this: *"JS does not seem to be loading on the page"*. What are the symptoms? What lead you to this conclusion?

Comment: Javascript is running before your dom is ready. PUT the JS at the bottom of body or add onLoad callback. Your menu isnt working because the selector is null (indicated by error meet-our-team:274 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at meet-our-team:274)

Comment: @kryger see my comment below with a link to the example of how it should work.

Comment: @mr.void I moved the JS to the bottom of the <body> and although there is no longer the error, the javascript is not causing the accordion menus to expand.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is execute before the DOM was loaded.

Check you HTML structure.

```
<!html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Here your style, title, meta -->
    <!-- Here your JS library if need -->
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- Here your html -->
  <!-- Here your JS code -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Try to encapsulate your JavaScript code in the DOM ready listner

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    // Here your JS code
  });
</script>
```

This event is fire when the DOM is ready to use.

**Update Step2**

As it write in your [model](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGQExQ?editors=1111). The `A` tag need to be inside the `DT` tag.

Comment: I made these changes and I am now getting an error on 'document.addEventListner('DOMContentLoaded', function(){' that the function does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, typing mistake. it's `addEventListener`

Comment: Thank you for the correction, but the javascript is still not working unfortunately. Here is the codepen template, that shows how the JS should react: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGQExQ

Comment: You down vote my answer because I got the first step to solve you problem... So fair...

Comment: @JakeP Ok, sorry for that.